# What plan(s) are needed to get Rails set up on AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm new to Amazon's cloud though I have used other cloud provides like Rackspace, Windows Azure and Heroku. I want to deploy my Ruby on Rails 4 application on Amazon but I am overwhelmed with all of the services Amazon offers. AWS, EC2, EBS, S3, SimpleDB, Elastic Beanstalk.... argh!!

My site is a relatively simple Rails app with a Postres database. There will not be much traffic at launch but we obviously hope it will grow and need to scale up.

What is a simple, no-frills plan that Amazon offers to get my app out there? I feel like I need to read 100 pages of documentation just to understand what it is that Amazon is offering.

Comment: Only 1 page is necessary until you want to build out a more customized infrastructure for your site. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Comment: IT says EB is beta. Is it stable enough to use for a production site?

Comment: I can't speak to that; I've never used it. If you have no clue what you're doing with AWS and leery of the `beta` tag on EB, I suggest **not** jumping in and running a production site on AWS. You're asking for headaches, IMO - consider starting with something more novice-friendly like Heroku while you learn the AWS ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are no *plans*. You sign-up for an AWS account, and you have access to whichever services you want to use.

Secondly, I can wholeheartedly recommend a single-instance Elastic Beanstalk environment to get started. It only uses 1 EC2 virtual server behind the scenes, but you get much better deployment options.

I can't speak to other services like Heroku.

Comment: thanks. I went ahead with EB and it appears that Elastic Beanstalk provides functionality that is in some sense, similar to Heroku where the platform figures out what is needed.